# Canvas Developer Guide / Run the Web App Locally

Tags: canvas, developer

### I try to run Web app locally following all instructions in [Canvas Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/quick_start_run_the_app_locally.htm). But get next exception:

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /examples/hello-world/index.jsp. Reason:

```
PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:665)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Powered by Jetty://

---

My index.jsp :

```
"<%@ page import="canvas.SignedRequest" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
<%
    // Pull the signed request out of the request body and verify/decode it.
    Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
    String[] signedRequest = parameters.get("signed_request");
    if (signedRequest == null) {%>
        This App must be invoked via a signed request!<%
        return;
    }
    String yourConsumerSecret=System.getenv("CANVAS_CONSUMER_SECRET");
    //String yourConsumerSecret="1818663124211010887";
    String signedRequestJson = SignedRequest.verifyAndDecodeAsJson(signedRequest[0], yourConsumerSecret);
%>"
```

"

```
<title>Hello World Canvas Example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sdk/css/canvas.css" />

<!-- Include all the canvas JS dependencies in one file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sdk/js/canvas-all.js"></script>
<!-- Third part libraries, substitute with your own -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/json2.js"></script>

<script>
    if (self === top) {
        // Not in Iframe
        alert("This canvas app must be included within an iframe");
    }

    Sfdc.canvas(function() {
        var sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
        // Save the token
        Sfdc.canvas.oauth.token(sr.oauthToken);
        Sfdc.canvas.byId('username').innerHTML = sr.context.user.fullName;
    });

</script>
```

```
<h1>Hello <span id='username'></span></h1>
```

I think maybe anything wrong with building app, but actually I don't know

### pom.xml :

"

< project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" >

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sfdc</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Salesforce Canvas Framework SDK</name>
<artifactId>sfdc-canvas-sdk</artifactId>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1-glassfish</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.v20100127</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.0.v20120127</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this for some of the JSON parsing in OAuthServlet -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20080701</version>
     </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for the proxy -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Newer version of this is needed for thew Base64 Encoding -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The maven app assembler plugin will generate a script that sets up the classpath and runs your project -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution1</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(Edit 1)
I change my pom.xml as you say

"

< project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" >

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sfdc</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Salesforce Canvas Framework SDK</name>
<artifactId>sfdc-canvas-sdk</artifactId>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1-glassfish</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.v20100127</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this for some of the JSON parsing in OAuthServlet -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20080701</version>
     </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for the proxy -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Newer version of this is needed for thew Base64 Encoding -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>${jetty.port}</port>
                    <idleTimeout>60000</idleTimeout>
                </httpConnector>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>${jetty.stop.port}</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The maven app assembler plugin will generate a script that sets up the classpath and runs your project -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution1</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

But now when I build get following exception:

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sfdc-canvas-sdk ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Ivan_Kliavakin\code\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\src\main\resources

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ sfdc-canvas-sdk ---

[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Ivan_Kliavakin\code\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\target\classes

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] \Users\Ivan_Kliavakin\code\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\src\main\java\Main.java:[29,35] error: package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio does not exist

[ERROR] \Users\Ivan_Kliavakin\code\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\src\main\java\Main.java:[30,35] error: package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl does not exist

[INFO] 2 errors

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 15.371 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-28T16:36:16+03:00

[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/281M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project sfdc-canvas-sdk: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] \Users\Ivan_Kliavakin\code\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\src\main\java\Main.java:[29,35] error: package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio does not exist

[ERROR] \Users\Ivan_Kliavakin\code\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\src\main\java\Main.java:[30,35] error: package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl does not exist

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] /cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the error log, this is caused due to a mismatch in the versions (relatively common occurence in Java world). In your `pom.xml` file, replace the portion related to jetty with this under the `plugins` section

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>${jetty.port}</port>
                        <idleTimeout>60000</idleTimeout>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>${jetty.stop.port}</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This should fix it.

Comment: I think about your question and find something similar(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264609/jetty-hello-world-example-not-compiling), but I am not fully understand what they mean and what and where I must use ';' instead of ':' as a path separator?

Comment: Yes, simply adding this to the pom.xml does not solve the problem. I am not a Maven or Jetty expert, so I don't know how to make it happen that the most recent version of Jetty is used. In webapp.bat I see that still an old version of Jetty is used, one that is not compatible with Java 1.8, the version that I have on my system.